# divisibility for quaternions

Tags: abstract-algebra

I wonder an identity for the quaternions. Let $q_1$ and $q_2$ are two integral quaternions.

When is the term $\frac{q_1}{q_2}$ is integral quaternions.

Does it hold if and only if $N(q_1)\mid N(q_2)$?

Thank you.

Comment: "$q_1|q_2$" isn't a term, it's a relation.  Do you mean "when is $\frac{q_1}{q_2}$ an integral quaternion, assuming $q_1$ and $q_2$ are?"

Comment: Yes. I mean when the term $\frac{q_1}{q_2}$ is a quaternion? Is there any property for this fraction? @rschwieb.

Comment: If that is the case, then I guess you want $N(q_2)|N(q_1)$ rather than the current order.

Comment: If $N(q_2)\mid N(q_1)$ holds, does it give that the term $\frac{q_1}{q_2}$ is integral quaternion?

Comment: Are you additionally assuming the quotient $N(q_1)/N(q_2)$ is an integer?  Because as long as they are nonzero, they will always divide.

Comment: Briefly, i want to learn that what are the necessary and sufficient conditions (if exists) to be the term $\frac{q_1}{q_2}$  integral quaternion?